Can I get video statistics with the YouTube API?
I get this error when I run trying to get the statistics:

'Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.'

It runs well without the last line.
This is the code:
function YoutubeScraper() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()

  var search = YouTube.Search.list ("snippet, id", {q: "searching youtube", maxResults: 30})

  var results = search.items.map((item) => [item.snippet.title, item.snippet.channelId, item.snippet.publishedAt])

  var ids = results.map ((id) => id[0]).join(",")

  var stats = YouTube.Videos.list ("statistics", {id: ids})

  var videoStats = stats.items.map((item) => [item.statistics.viewCount, item.statistics.likeCount, item.statistics.commentCount])
  
  sheet.getRange(2,1, results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results)
  sheet.getRange(2,3, videoStats.length, results[0].length).setValues(videoStats)
}

I was hoping to get a list on my active sheet with the query results and their stats. Can get the results but not the stats. I've tried changing the range on the stats but it doesn't work. Runs well without the last line, my active sheet on Google Docs gets populated with the results (title, channelId, and publish time), but cannot get the last line to work.

Modification points:

I think that in your script, the values of var ids = results.map ((id) => id[0]).join(",") are item.snippet.title of results. By this, stats.items is []. I guessed that this is the reason for your current issue of Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1..
In this case, it is required to use the video IDs to YouTube.Videos.list.
Also, in your situation, I think that the values can be put into cells by one call using the channel ID.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
Before you use this script, please enable YouTube Data API at Advanced Google services.
function YoutubeScraper() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var search = YouTube.Search.list("snippet, id", { q: "searching youtube", maxResults: 30 });
  var results = search.items.map((item) => [item.snippet.title, item.snippet.channelId, item.snippet.publishedAt]);

  // --- I modified the below script.
  if (search.items.length == 0) return;
  var ids = search.items.map(({ id: { videoId } }) => videoId || "").filter(String);
  var stats = YouTube.Videos.list(["statistics", "snippet"], { id: ids });
  var obj = stats.items.reduce((o, { snippet, statistics }) => (o[snippet.channelId] = [statistics.viewCount || 0, statistics.likeCount || 0, statistics.commentCount || 0], o), {});
  var values = results.map(e => [...e, ...(obj[e[1]] ? obj[e[1]] : Array(3).fill(null))]);
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}


When this script is run, the values are put into cells of the active sheet.

Reference:

Videos: list


Thank you so much, Tanaike!!! I wish I could fully understand the solution, but alas, I cannot. Thanks again!

@Danilo Reuben About my added part, at var ids =, the video IDs are retrieved from results. And, at var stats =, the values are retrieved using the video IDs. At var obj =, an object is created for searching the channel IDs. At var values =, the result array is created using results and obj. At the last line, the result array is put into the active sheet. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Thanks again, Tanaike! I just accepted the solution. And thanks for the explanation, it does indeed clarify the process.

@Danilo Reuben Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
